# Traverse files and replace all tabs to two spaces

Tags: shell, tabs, spaces

I want to replace all tabs with 2 spaces in all files in my project directory.
Here is the code I have written but it is not working as expected.

Tabs are as it is in the files.

```
for i in *
do
  sed 's/tab/spacespace/g' "${i}" > temp.txt && mv temp.txt "${i}"
done
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use [`expand`](http://man.cx/expand)

```
for f in *; do
    expand -t2 "$f" > tmp && mv tmp "$f"
done
```

`expand` is recommended option for below reason:

e.g. consider tabsize=8. (Larger tabsize chosen for ease of explanation.)

then `<LINE_START>abc<TAB>pqrs` should be represented as below:

```
T       T       T <~~~~~~ Tab markers on every 8th column, since tabsize=8.
abc     pqrs
-->     <-- This gap is 5 characters, not 8.
```

If someone blindly replaces all tabs by N spaces, then it will be wrong. That will however, work for replacing LEADING tabs.

`expand` utility smartly takes care of the situation mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Found a silly mistake in my code. This is working

```
for i in * 
do
  sed 's/\t/  /g' "${i}" > temp.txt && mv temp.txt "${i}"
done
```

Comment: expand is recommended option (See other answer). besides, even in sed, you need not use redirection + mv. sed already has a `-i` option.